# Powerpoint data extraction with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

This past week I have been working in VBA on an excel macro that pulls specific data from several power point slides. I was able to write up a macro that was able to pull all the details in the Title object and place them all in a single Column. I need to be able to pull data from all the other fields, but they are tables and not text boxes. I was able to figure out how to extract the contents of the text boxes, but I am not able to figure out how to refer to the tables inside the slide. Once I’m able to refer to the tables for these details I only need to pull specific details from the tables. I have searched around and was not able to find anything specific on how to extract data from tables within PowerPoint slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using code I found in the last post of [this thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/746855-exporting-table-data-powerpoint-excel-using-vba-getting-error-438-object-doesnt-support-property.html)

```
Sub DataTransfer()

    Dim shp As Shape, i%, j%

'    Dim colCount As Integer
'    Dim rowCount As Integer


    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim rng As Object

    Set rng = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Range("a1")  ' start at top of worksheet

    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

        For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes

            If shp.HasTable Then

                With shp.Table

'                    colCount = .Columns.Count
'                    rowCount = .Rows.Count

                    For rowNum = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1

                        For j = 0 To 4
                            rng.Offset(rowNum, j).Value = (.Cell(rowNum + 1, j + 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange)
                        Next j

'                        rng.Offset(rowNum, 4).Interior.Color = (.Cell(rowNum + 1, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange)

                    Next rowNum

                    Set rng = rng.Offset(rowNum + 1) ' 1 blank row between tables

                End With
            End If
        Next shp
    Next i


End Sub
```

The code sample above works on a 5x5 table. However, if you want to collect more columns change this line:
For j = 0 To 4
to how ever many columns you'd like (e.g. For j = 0 to 5 for 6 columns)

You could change that number for columns to a variable as a parameter for the sub. I'm sure there's a way to rewrite the code using a For Each loop through all columns. But this should get you started.